# How to convert %a tag to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a Rails application that has a simple notification system. Many people are part of this project and sadly we didn't stick to a standard coding convention. There are some weird problems happening in certain situations and I found out that these occur because they were linked to using `%a` instead of `link_to`.

I then embarked on a journey of changing each `%a` to `link_to` and have already converted the simple stuff and then this boggled me:

```
.dropdown{"data-behavior" => "notifications"}
  %a.dropdown-toggle.nav-link{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-behavior" => "notifications-link", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
    %i.fa.fa-bell
    %span{"data-behavior" => "unread-count"}
  .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenuButton", "data-behavior" => "notification-items"}
```

How do I convert this to a `link_to`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's no `href` - you can pass `nil` there:

```
= link_to nil, class: 'dropdown-toggle nav-link',
  type: :button,
  aria:{ expanded: false, haspopup: true},
  data: { behavior: "notifications-link",  toggle: :dropdown} do
  %i.fa.fa-bell
  - # and so on
```

but for places where it's actually not a link - there' no much sense in making it a `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to nil, type: :button,
  class: 'dropdown-toggle nav-link',
  aria: { expanded: false, haspopup: true },
  data: { behavior: 'notifications-link', toggle: 'dropdown' } do

  %i.fa.fa-bell
  %span{"data-behavior" => "unread-count"}
```

Should be ok with this code